# $\mathbb E(X_{T \wedge n}) = \mathbb E(X_0)$, where $ T \wedge n := \min(T, n)$, $\forall n$

Tags: probability, proof-explanation

> If $X$ is martingale and $T$ is a stopping time, then $X_{T \wedge n}$
> is a martingale, so that in particular, $\mathbb E(X_{T \wedge n}) = \mathbb E(X_0)$,
> where $ T \wedge n := \min(T, n)$, $\forall n$.

Why is $X_{T \wedge n}$ a martingale, and why does $\mathbb E(X_{T \wedge n}) = \mathbb E(X_0)$, $\forall n$?

Comment: This is proved in many books including K L Chung's book.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Which book of Chung? It is listed as a theorem in my book, but the author does not provide a proof or detail explanations.

Comment: See the Corollary on p. 325 of Chung's A Course in Probability Theory. The second part is entirely trivial since $EY_n$ does not depend on $n$ for any martingale $(Y_n)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check integrability and adaptation, but for the martingale property, considering the filtration $(\mathcal{F}_n)_{n \ge 0}$ to which $(X_n)_{n \ge 0}$ is adapted, and since $T$ is a stopping time so that $\{T \le n\}$ and its complementary $\{T > n\}$ belong to $\mathcal{F}_n$, you have
$$ \mathbb{E}[X_{T \wedge (n+1)} |\mathcal{F}_n] =  \mathbb{E}[X_{n+1} \mathbf{1}_{T > n} |\mathcal{F}_n] + \mathbb{E}[X_T \mathbf{1}_{T \le n} |\mathcal{F}_n], $$
which leads to, using that we can take out the indicator functions and that $X_T \mathbf{1}_{T \le n}$ is $\mathcal{F}_n$ measurable,
$$ \mathbb{E}[X_{T \wedge (n+1)} |\mathcal{F}_n] = \mathbf{1}_{T > n}  \mathbb{E}[X_{n+1} |\mathcal{F}_n] + \mathbf{1}_{T \le n}  X_T = \mathbf{1}_{T > n} X_n + \mathbf{1}_{T \le n}  X_T = X_{T \wedge n}. $$

Comment: Why $\mathbb{E}[X_{T \wedge (n+1)} |\mathcal{F}_n] =  \mathbb{E}[X_{n+1} \mathbf{1}_{T > n} |\mathcal{F}_n] + \mathbb{E}[X_T \mathbf{1}_{T \le n} |\mathcal{F}_n]$?

Comment: Either $T > n$ which means $T \ge n+1$ hence $T \wedge(n+1) = n+1$ or $T \le n$ i.e. $T < n+1$ in which case $T \wedge (n+1) = T$.